# Autofill commands with own defined class

Tags: glossaries

I have the problem with autofilling commands. Now I am writing an own .cls-File with all packages that I need.

When I use e.g. the code `\gls{}`, it will be marked red and the autofill function is disabled.
When I write `\usepackage{glossaries}` in the main part of my file and not in die .cls-File, then it works normally.

How can I fix it?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your editor. Which one are you using?

Comment: I use TeXstudio